# Stack Exchange App

Tags: discussion

I think this is on-topic. If not, I'll close the question.

I've seen at least one question, maybe more, on here about a Stack Exchange app for Windows Phone. However, to the best of my knowledge, there aren't any very nice ones. I'm currently working on a UWP app for the Stack Exchange network. However, it's my first time doing an app like this. I know at least several of the users on here are developers, and I thought perhaps some of you (some of whom I know are far more experienced than me) would be interested in working on it if I'd move it to GitHub?

If people are interested I'll move it over to GitHub. Otherwise I don't want to put it out there for the general public to get their grimy hands on. :)

Currently it's in a very, very basic state. It has read-only capabilities for all questions on Stack Exchange.

Anyway, to conclude, please let me know if you would be interested in helping with this.

UPDATE: I'm beginning to put the app into a very gradual closed beta. Let me know if you'd like to help test.

Comment: I would like to test the app. But currently I only have Windows 8.1 on my phone. Does this app work on WP 8.1?

Comment: @KolappanNathan No, it's Windows 10 only. But you're fine for now, because I've been so busy lately that I've not had much time to do anything on it :P

Comment: Okay RareNCool.

Comment: I'd like to be part of the beta tests, sign me up

Comment: I'll need an email address to do that. You can hit me at esbe118@live.com.

Comment: @RareNCool I want to participate in the beta and I have mailed you my email address associated with the store.

Comment: @RareNCool i appreciate your efforts, may I have a look on this

Comment: Count me in too, I'd like to help! Just sent you an email

Comment: @User5 Sorry about the late reply! If you're still interested, pop me an email! The alpha is well on its way!

Comment: @Mathemanic Sorry about the late reply! If you're still interested, pop me an email! The alpha is well on its way!